# XPATH extract doesn't get nodes with attributes

Tags: xpath

Here's a stupid XPATH question.  The code is PL/SQL but it shouldn't matter.

```
lx_a := XMLTYPE('<rfs-graph><graphml>foo</graphml><rfs-graph>');
lx_b := lx_a.extract('/rfs-graph/graphml[1]');
dbms_output.put_line(lx_b.getStringVal());
```

When run, the result is

```
<graphml>foo</graphml>
```

But when this code is run:

```
lx_a := XMLTYPE('<rfs-graph><graphml xmlns="abc">foo</graphml></rfs-graph>');
lx_b := lx_a.extract('/rfs-graph/graphml[1]');
dbms_output.put_line(lx_b.getStringVal());
```

it fails because lx_b is null.

The only difference is that the graphml element has an attribute.

How can I select the graphml element regardless of whether it has attributes or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xmlns="abc"` is not a standard attribute, it is a [namespace prefix declaration](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp).  In this case because the prefix is omitted it is in fact specifying the default namespace for that node (and all child nodes)

The reason why your XPath is not matching in the second case is because the name of the node is not just `graphml`, its `abc:graphml`, i.e. its in the `abc` namesapce.  Your XPath should look something like this.

```
/rfs-graph/a:graphml[1]
```

Where the prefix `a` has been mapped to the `abc` namespace, I *think* the way to do this in PL/SQL is as follows

```
lx_b := lx_a.extract('/rfs-graph/a:graphml[1]', 'xmlns:a="abc"');
```

But I'm not sure as I've never written a single line of PL/SQL before now.

Comment: Well, now you have!  It works perfectly, and you can put PL/SQL on your resume.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Actually it hasn't attribute but xml namespace declaration. So your xpath is looking for graphml element from null namespace but there is only graphml element from "abc" namespace. Therefore it doesn't find anything.

You could use e.g. following xpath

```
/rfs-graph/node()[local-name() = 'graphml' and namespace-uri() = 'abc']
```